# I done the listview, after click the listview it can show image for url mysql in android studio

Tags: java, android, listview

This is `timetable.java` file display listview:

```
public class timetable extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;

    // Let's set up a string array to inflate the listview with
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    String address = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/conn.php";

    InputStream is = null;

    String line = null;

    String result = null;

    String[] data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timetable);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

        // allow network in main thread
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy((new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build()));

        // retrieve
        getData();

        // adapter
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        // register onClickListener to handle click events on each item
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            // argument position gives the index of item which is clicked
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedClass = data[position];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedClass+" selected",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent (timetable.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("SELECTED_CLASS", selectedClass);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void getData() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(address);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            is = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // read is content into a string
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // parse json data
        try {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject jo = null;

            data = new String[ja.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                data[i] = jo.getString("classname");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is `SecondActivity.java` file:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView iv;
private Bitmap bitmap;
PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String selectedClass = "";

    if(bundle != null){
        selectedClass = bundle.getString("SELECTED_CLASS");
    }

    String imageUrl = "";

     if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK SEMINAR 1"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bs1.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK SEMINAR 2"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bs2.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 1"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt1.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 10"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt10.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 2"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt2.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 3"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt3.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 4"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt4.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 5"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt5.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 6"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt6.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 7"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt7.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 8"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt8.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 9"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt9.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - DEWAN KULIAH 1"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/dk1.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - DEWAN KULIAH 2"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/dk2.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - DEWAN KULIAH 3"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/dk3.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - DEWAN KULIAH 4"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/dk4.jpg";

    bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(iv);
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src){
    try{
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    }catch (Exception e){
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

[listview output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhkQ8.png)
[retrieve image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH8MZ.png)

i have 16 classname in listview, i want do when user click the each classname it will retrieve a picture (timetable) store from url mysql. each classname have different image. now i done the listview but when click the all list it also retrieve the same image. my idea is use if else but i don't know the code.

Comment: what is your class names?

Comment: classname is store in mysql i reterieve it to listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass value `selectedclass` from `Timetable` to `SecondActivity`, then use `Intent.putExtra()` and update your `onItemClick` method ad below:

**Timetable.java:**

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        // argument position gives the index of item which is clicked
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            String selectedclass = data[position];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedclass+" selected",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent (timetable.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("SELECTED_CLASS", selectedclass);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

If you want to get value `selectedclass` from `SecondActivity`, use `getString()`.

**SecondActivity.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String selectedClass = "";

    if(bundle != null){
        selectedClass = bundle.getString("SELECTED_CLASS");
    }

    String imageUrl = "";

     if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK SEMINAR 1"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bs1.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK SEMINAR 2"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bs2.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 1"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt1.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 2"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt2.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 3"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt3.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 4"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt4.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 5"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt5.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 6"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt6.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 7"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt7.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 8"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt8.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 9"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt9.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - BILIK TUTORIAL 10"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/bt10.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - DEWAN KULIAH 1"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/dk1.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - DEWAN KULIAH 2"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/dk2.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - DEWAN KULIAH 3"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/dk3.jpg";
    else if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("PERP - DEWAN KULIAH 4"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/dk4.jpg";

    bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(iv);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much...i have 16 classname in listview, i want do when user click the each classname it will retrieve a picture (timetable) store from url mysql. each classname have different image. now i done the listview but when click the all list it also retrieve the same image. my idea is use if else but i don't know the code...top have my output image

Comment: i already follow your way but still not work...I have updated SecondActivity.java

Comment: did you applied if else condition in your second activity?

Comment: ya top have my the updated timetable.java and SecondActivity.java coding, can u help me see what problem?

Comment: You are always comparing your selected class with bs2. Change it. If your selected class is XXX and the image for XXX is http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/XXX.jpg". then you can use>>          if (selectedClass.equalsIgnoreCase("XXX"))
        imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/timetable/class/XXX.jpg";

Comment: Make sure your class names are: bs1, bs2, bt1 to bt10, dk1 to dk4

Comment: ya is my classname not same with the XXX.jpg only haha

Comment: is it working now? if not, put log in your second activity to know the selected class what you get from first activity.

Comment: Glad to know....... if my solution helps you to solve your problem then mark this answer as accepted and give an up vote. Thank you